# Maintaining secrecy of secret hats

Tags: discussion, feature-request, winter-bash-2014, secret-hats, winter-bash-2015

Winter Bash 2014 was fun, especially the "secret hat" concept.

However, by the time I found out about it, all the secret hats were not 'secret' anymore. I don't mean that revealing secret hats is a bad idea, but it was a bit annoying. I have the following questions (which I hope would relevant in next year's event)

1. Suppose I get a secret hat and I have a pretty good guess about how I got it. Is there anywhere I can state this to the SE officials to get a "Eureka!" hat, without revealing it publicly, so that others can also try guessing the secret?
2. I have quite a few ideas for the secret hats for next year. I suppose others have, too. Maybe SE could create some place where you can send such suggestions, and they could use the best ones.
3. Shouldn't next year have more hats, secret ones especially, to make it more difficult to get all the hats?
4. Do the hats have anything to do with the badges?
5. "Winter Bash" wouldn't be that appropriate in places like Australia, maybe something like "Christmas Bash" or "New Year Bash" would have been better. I suppose it's too late to change it, though.

Comment: Do you know how many active users there are across all the StackExchange sites? (Hint: lots). Imagine even a fraction of them individually contacting SE officials saying "I've just discovered hat X, please give me an award".

Comment: @JonW Thinking about this.... It would be possible to have an online form, where you could enter guesses using combo-boxes. To prevent brute-forcing, people would get only 3 guesses per hat.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Or just do away with the Eureka hat altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anywhere I can state this to the SE officials to get a "Eureka!" hat, without revealing it publicly?

Yes. Use the [Contact Us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) form (using Other as the reason), linked from the footer. The email will go to the community team, who are Stack Exchange employees and will not be public.

> Maybe SE could create some place where you can send such suggestions, and they could use the best ones

You can always post a question here on MSE, asking for hat ideas for winterbash 2015. No guarantee that any will be accepted though...

> Shouldn't next year have more hats, secret ones especially, to make it more difficult to get all the hats?

Should it? I don't know that it should. It is supposed to be *fun* and encourage certain behaviors. The secret ones can be difficult enough to get - we wouldn't want to end up with secret hats that no one managed to get.

> Do the hats have anything to do with the badges?

Some hats are based on badges, so they would essentially be awarded if the badge was also awarded. Not all of them are.

> I suppose it's too late to change it, though.

Kinda. We can consider a more globally appropriate name nearer the time.

Answer (score -1):

Just answering your point 5 - While Winter is obviously northern hemisphere specific, your alternatives are possibly less appropriate:

- Christmas is not celebrated by everybody
- New Year is not the 1st of January for everyone

So I propose a new name:

**Annual Hat Challenge**

There you go :-)

Comment: Hat Hunt Event sounds better to me. ;)